Read parquet by chunks with DuckDB and Julia
I've tried the following code:
con = DBInterface.connect(DuckDB.DB)
query = "SELECT * FROM range(1000000000000) t(i)"
res = DBInterface.execute(con, query, DuckDB.StreamResult)

# fetch the first three chunks
for i in 1:3
    chunk = DuckDB.nextDataChunk(res)
    DuckDB.destroy_data_chunk(chunk)
end
DBInterface.close!(res)
DBInterface.close!(con)
GC.gc(true)

but it's not really reading by chunks. Instead, it tries to read the whole 1000000000000 rows in a single result and blow up my RAM. I got this code from the tests, though.
Am I missing something?

Looking at the code I doubt very much that this is actually creating a streaming result.
The Julia package is no longer maintained and this test has probably silently broken in the mean time.
The Stmt object can be created with MaterializedResult or StreamResult
function execute(con::Connection, sql::AbstractString, params::DBInterface.StatementParams)
    stmt = Stmt(con, sql, MaterializedResult)
    try
        return execute(stmt, params)
    finally
        _close_stmt(stmt) # immediately close, don't wait for GC
    end
end

It seems this always creates a MaterializedResult
You can break this up and substitute MaterializedResult with StreamResult and it should work.

I defined my own execute function replacing MaterializedResult for StreamResult, but it got the same behavior ie it didn't work.

Actually this works nicely if you run it from the file. I assume that this is DBInterface issue.

What do you mean by "run it from the file"?

If you put your code to a file with an extension .jl and then run it like julia your_file.jl

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
